# ¿Hay forma de asignar un client id personalizado o sobreescribir el id que da socketIO?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, socket.io, websocket

estoy trabjando en un api con sockets en conjunto, quisiera consultar si hay alguna forma de asignar un cliente id personalizado o especifico cuando el usuario se conecta, me gustaria brindarle al usuaro un id que viniera desde un Bd ya sea su username o su propio id de BD o algo de ese estilo pero no se bien como se hace. como ejemplo tengo este porcion de codigo:

En el fronted

```
var socket = io()`   
    if (!params.has('nombre') || !params.has('sala')) {
        window.location = 'index.html';
        throw new Error('El nombre y sala son necesarios');
    }
    
    var usuario = {
        nombre: params.get('nombre'),
        sala: params.get('sala')
    };
    
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('Conectado al servidor');
    
        socket.emit('entrarChat', usuario, function(resp) {
            // console.log('Usuarios conectados', resp);
            renderizarUsuarios(resp);
        });
    });
```

Y esta a la escucha en el backend

```
    const { io } = require('../server');
    const {Usuarios} = require('../clases/usuarios')
    const { crearMensaje } = require('../utils/utils')
    
    
    
    io.on('connection', (client) => {
    
        // al dispararse este evento en el frontend se espera que se envie un usuario un callback
        client.on('entrarChat', (data , callback)=>{
            // data es al informacion a parte del callback que se envia desde el fonrtend
            if (!data.nombre || !data.sala) {
                return callback({               
                    msj: 'nombre y sala son  necesarios'
                })
            }
    
            //une a un cliente a una sala, si esta instruccion no se pasa entonce4s todos van a una sala comun sin filtros
            client.join(data.sala);
    
            // toma el nombre del parametro clied del socket, ya que este crea un id automaticamente
           usuarios.agregarPersona(client.id, data.nombre , data.sala);
    
           client.broadcast.to(data.sala).emit('listaPersonas', usuarios.getPersonasPorSala(data.sala));
           client.broadcast.to(data.sala).emit('crearMensaje', crearMensaje('Administrador', `${ data.nombre } se unió`));       
            
            callback(usuarios.getPersonasPorSala(data.sala))      
        });
```

entonces en el la linea

```
usuarios.agregarPersona(client.id, data.nombre , data.sala);
```

Que si no mal entiendo este se genera automaticamente, no estoy seguro si entoy entiendo mal, entonce quisiera saber si se puede en el frontend asignar un id personalizado al cliente para que pueda escuchar los eventos? no se como realmente se hace eso y si esa es la forma correcta de manejarlo o como es que hace?

En este caso estoy pidiendo el parametro sala pero lo que busco es hacer una comunicacion 1 a 1.

Comment: pudiste solucionarlo? tengo el mismo problema, o como devolver el id generado tambien me gustaria saber.